# Create Polynomial function- unbound identifier in module

Tags: racket, tail-recursion

In my test I was asked to write a function createPolynomial that takes as arguments a list of  numbers 0, … , −1 and returns as output a function. The returned function takes a number 0 and return the value of the polynomial 0 ⋅ 0 + ⋯ + −1 ⋅ −1 at 0. To this end, I used the built-in pl expt function taking two numbers  and , and returning ^

i was given a partial code which I will post down below with my answer and wanted to test my answer at home but I can't make it run although my teacher marked my answer as correct. Any help would be appreciated

here is the partial code:

```
(: createPolynomial : (Listof Number) -> <-fill in->)
(define (createPolynomial coeffs)
 (: poly : (Listof Number) Number Integer Number ->
Number)
 (define (poly argsL x power accum)
 (if <-fill in->
 <-fill in->
 <-fill in-> )
  (: polyX : Number -> Number)
     (define (polyX x)
     fill in)
     fill in)

And here is my answer:

   (: createPolynomial : (Listof Number) -> (Number -> Number))
(define (createPolynomial coeffs)
  (: poly : (Listof Number) Number Integer Number ->
     Number)
  (define (poly argsL x power accum)
    (if (null? argsL)
        accum
    (poly (rest argsL) x (+ power 1) (+ accum (* (first argsL) (expt x power))))))
  (: polyX : Number -> Number)
  (define (polyX x)
    (poly coeffs x 0 0))
  (polyX x))



and here are some test for the code:

> (createPolynomial '(1 2 4 2))
- : (Number -> Number)
#<procedure:polyX>
(define p2345 (createPolynomial '(2 3 4 5)))
(test (p2345 0) =>
 (+ (* 2 (expt 0 0)) (* 3 (expt 0 1)) (* 4 (expt 0 2)) (* 5
(expt 0 3))))
(test (p2345 4) =>
 (+ (* 2 (expt 4 0)) (* 3 (expt 4 1)) (* 4 (expt 4 2)) (* 5
(expt 4 3))))
(test (p2345 11) => (+ (* 2 (expt 11 0)) (* 3 (expt 11 1)) (* 4
(expt 11 2)) (* 5 (expt 11 3))))
(define p536 (createPolynomial '(5 3 6)))
(test (p536 11) => (+ (* 5 (expt 11 0)) (* 3 (expt 11 1)) (* 6
(expt 11 2))))
(define p_0 (createPolynomial '()))
(test (p_0 4) => 0)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
x: unbound identifier in module in: x
```

I'm guessing It has to do something with the brackets but I can't figure out what and where...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createPolynomial` is a function that returns a function of type `(Number -> Number)` - it's *curried*. You are returning the *application* `(polyX x)` where `x` really is unbound. Convert this into a function by wrapping it in a lambda:

```
(λ (x) (polyX x))
```

... and the 5 tests pass.

Comment: Do you mean like this? (: createPolynomial : (Listof Number) -> (Number -> Number))
(define (createPolynomial coeffs)
  (: poly : (Listof Number) Number Integer Number ->
     Number)
  (define (poly argsL x power accum)
    (if (null? argsL)
        accum
    (poly (rest argsL) x (+ power 1) (+ accum (* (first argsL) (expt x power))))))
  (: polyX : Number -> Number)
  (define (polyX x)
    (poly coeffs x 0 0))
  (λ (x) (polyX x))) Because I'm getting the errors *define: not an identifier in: (x) and unsaved editor:14:3: λ: unbound identifier in module in: λ
  #(410 1)

Comment: It seems to work for me. Maybe unicode `λ` is not supported — try `lambda`